# Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed block main thread

Tags: android, garbage-collection, renderer

Every time I press home button to exit any app on my phone, the following log will be appeared after one or two second. Then my app stuck one second.

```
I/art     ( 6911): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 49911(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 218(3MB) LOS objects, 10% free, 66MB/74MB, paused 9.440ms total 145.824ms
I/art     (19772): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 67472(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 43(1281KB) LOS objects, 2% free, 191MB/195MB, paused 8.694ms total 82.973ms
```

From the method profiling, `ThreadedRenderer.mSyncAndDrawFrame` cost a little long time on main thread.
[image]

I wanna know what's the problem?  (device is Android 5.1)